# Basic Input field Validation in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JavaScript, so I started learning from Forms. Kindly have a look at code and suggest.

I am trying to validate the first field only, it must contain string, but not numeric and also should not contain alpha numeric characters. But if I enter alpha numeric characters, it does not show the alert message window. Kindly advise.

```
function checkFields()
{
    var tname = document.getElementById("t0_name").value;
    var texpense = document.getElementById("t1_expense").value;
    var tdate = document.getElementById("t2_date").value;
    var tamt = document.getElementById("t3_amt").value;
    var tstatus = document.getElementById("t4_status").value;
    var temail = document.getElementById("t5_email").value;
    var alphanumeric = /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/;
    if (tname == null || tname ==  "") {
        document.getElementById("t0_name").style.border = "1px solid black";
        alert('should not be blank');
    } else if (!isNaN(tname)) {
        alert('Should not be Numeric');
        document.getElementById("t0_name").style.border = "1px solid red";
    } else if (/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(tname)) {
        alert('Input is not alphanumeric');
    }
}
```

Thanks
Balkar

Comment: "Alpha numeric" includes virtually all characters (*alphabet* and *numeric*)... So what *should* it contain?!

Comment: the condition is that the input field only have to accept characters, no number and not even alpha numbers.

Comment: So you want to allow exclusively the characters A-Z? "Alpha numbers" isn't a thing, it's just *numbers*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex to check for only characters and not alphanumeric i.e. characters and numbers.

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test('Abc') // true

/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test('a1') // false
```

In your regex you've specified numbers from 0-9 so that's why it returns true on alphanumeric.

You can also use \D i.e. a non-digit

```
/^[\D]+$/.test('A')
```

The + sign before the $ is for one or more characters.

Answer (score -1):

var alphanumeric = /[^a-zA-Z]/; done ... thanks